# Несколько страниц входа

Tags: asp.net, c#

Уважаемые коллеги, подскажите, пожалуйста, как задать несколько страниц входа? То есть, попросту говоря, для каталога `~/Cat1` происходит редирект на `Cat1Login.aspx`, для `~/Cat2`, соответственно, - `Cat2Login.aspx`. Что и где нужно прописать в файлах `web.config` соответствующих каталогов?

Answer (score 1):

Прописать в конфиге это нельзя.
Вы можете прописать в конфиге один адрес, а в его обработчике уже смотреть, какой пришел ReturnUrl, и в зависимости от этого делать редирект на разные страницы логина